# Tweepy for Twitter API v2 - problem with place fields

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to extract the tweets' place fields through tweepy paginator, but
why does python gives error about 'places'?

I did the exact same thing with user fields and there were no issue

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='____')

puma_tweets = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                 query = 'puma -is:retweet lang:en place_country:US',
                                 user_fields = ['id', 'username', 'name'],
                                 place_fields = ['id','full_name', 'country', 'geo', 'name', 'place_type'],
                                 tweet_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                                 expansions = 'author_id',
                                 max_results=500, limit = 20):
    time.sleep(1)
    puma_tweets.append(response)


result = []
user_dict = {}
place_dict = {}

for response in puma_tweets:

    for user in response.includes['users']:
        user_dict[user.id] = {'id': user.id,
                              'username': user.username, 
                              'name': user.name,
                              'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],
                             }
        
        
    for place in response.includes['places']:
        place_dict[place.id] = {'id': place.id,
                                'full_name': place.full_name
                             }

    for tweet in response.data:

        author_info = user_dict[tweet.author_id]

        result.append({'author_id': tweet.author_id,
                       'username': author_info['username'],
                       'text': tweet.text,
                       'geo': tweet.geo
                      }) 


df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: I m facing the same issue. Did you find any resolution to this issue?